# How to merge multiple deployment yaml files in k8s into one yaml file without using the separator '---'?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks

As mentioned above, I want to merge multiple deployment yaml files in k8s into one yaml file, but because of the project, I can't use the separator "---".

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ConfigMap
  metadata:
    name: cm1
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ConfigMap
  metadata:
    name: cm2

$ kubectl apply -f list.yaml
configmap/cm1 created
configmap/cm2 created
```